# Abort request and `return;` based on variable (without using if?)

Tags: nginx

### What I have:

```
# nginx.conf
http {
    map "$request_uri" $abort {
        default 0;
        "~*example" 1;
    }
    include sites-enabled/*.conf;
    # etc
}
```

```
# sites-enabled/example.com.conf
server {
    listen 80;
    location ~ \.js {
        if ($abort = 1) {
            return 500;
        }
    }
    # etc
}
# sites-enabled/example.net.conf
# sites-enabled/example.org.conf
# etc.
```

### What is the problem:

- I used [`map`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) because [*if is evil*](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/). Now, `$abort` has a flag, knowing whether to proceed or not.
- I don't know how to utilise that variable other than in an `if` statement. [These comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53578968/is-it-possible-to-use-variable-with-redirect-code-in-nginx-configuration) confirm.
- An [`if`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#if) is allowed only no deeper than the `server{}` context. I have 12 sites, 3 `server{}`s each.

### What I want:

Evaluate `$abort` and tell Nginx to `return 500` somewhere on the shared `http {}` level.

Avoid repeating the `if` for every `server {}` of every virtual host.

I know I can put the `if` into e.g. `snippets/abort.conf` and include it, but that seems like cluttering and waste of resources. I hope there is a more elegant way. Do you know any?

Comment: Just to clarify: the `if` itself is not a problem, having to repeat it is.

Comment: Nope. Just use `include` or may be some sort of templating to generate your server blocks (if applicable)

Comment: If you look at your linked document, `if` in a `location` context is only 100% safe with `return` and `rewrite...last`. Your conditional abort statement uses a `return` and is therefore 100% safe.

Comment: @RichardSmith thank you for your input, like I said my problem is cluttering and having to repeat the config across all `server`s; I'm looking for a way to tell Nginx to stop once and for all sites, no matter how many there are. The **without using if?** part in the title may have been confusing. It refers to `if` needing to be no deeper than `server` context.